# YouTube Data API not returning channel data for some accounts

Tags: swift, macos, youtube-data-api

I am trying to fetch channel user data from the following YouTube Data API endpoint:
[Channels: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) using this URL:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id%2Csnippet&mine=true`.

The user data is used for account identification and live streaming in a desktop app.

I can't create a "wrapper" YouTube account to access YouTube without:

- channel id, `id`, and
- channel name, `title`.

The problem is that the YouTube API provides the data for **some** accounts. I own three YouTube accounts and four channels and currently only one doesn't work.

The API returns the following data:

```
▿ 3 elements
  ▿ 0 : 2 elements
    - key : "kind"
    - value : youtube#channelListResponse
  ▿ 1 : 2 elements
    - key : "pageInfo"
    ▿ value : 2 elements
      ▿ 0 : 2 elements
        - key : resultsPerPage
        - value : 5
      ▿ 1 : 2 elements
        - key : totalResults
        - value : 0
  ▿ 2 : 2 elements
    - key : "etag"
    - value : afx3VqgXQBJVZZO3RVos5k1JEM0
```

The valid JSON response looks like this:

```
▿ 4 elements
  ▿ 0 : 2 elements
    - key : "items"
    ▿ value : 1 element
      ▿ 0 : 4 elements
        ▿ 0 : 2 elements
          - key : etag
          - value : SOME_ETAG
        ▿ 1 : 2 elements
          - key : kind
          - value : youtube#channel
        ▿ 2 : 2 elements
          - key : id
          - value : SOME_ID
        ▿ 3 : 2 elements
          - key : snippet
          ▿ value : 5 elements
            ▿ 0 : 2 elements
              - key : localized
              ▿ value : 2 elements
                ▿ 0 : 2 elements
                  - key : title
                  - value : SOME_TITLE
                ▿ 1 : 2 elements
                  - key : description
                  - value : 
            ▿ 1 : 2 elements
              - key : title
              - value : SOME_TITLE
            ▿ 2 : 2 elements
              - key : description
              
              ...
```

What I tried so far:

- verified that the Web API Explorer shows the same issue.
- verified that the permissions are the same.
- verified that the accounts have all the same features enabled.

This issue is new, everything was working a few months ago and I have not found any error in the response.

Comment: Isn't this something you should contact YouTube support about? I fail to see how this is a programming question.

Comment: Clearly, you haven't worked with Youtube...  this is Youtube support. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/support

Comment: That doesn't necessarily make the question suitable for stackoverflow.

Comment: I don't want to live on this planet anymore.

Comment: (Off-topic) Which tool does you use to convert JSON into this style? It's cool and convenient

Comment: @Darkwonder: What do you mean by (quote): *I can't create a "wrapper" YouTube account to access YouTube...*? I mean: what is a *wrapper account*? The API does not define such concept.

Comment: @asuka: Personally, I find JSON much more readable than the OP's formatted text above.

Comment: @Darkwonder: Can you post the ID of a channel for which `Channels.list` does not produce the metadata you're needing? A channel's [`id`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#id) and [`title`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#snippet.title) are public info (accessible to everyone).

Comment: @Darkwonder: On the other hand, Joakim Danielson is very much correct: SO is not Google support, by no means (in spite of Google developers site claiming the contrary). Google has its [own issue tracker site](http://issuetracker.google.com/).

Comment: @asuka this is Xcode debug output. The drawback is that you cant copy/paste it in any other JSON tool.

Comment: @stvar Thank you for the answers and the feedback. A wrapper account is a wrapper object which contains abstract account data (facebook, youtube, periscope). You are correct, the Youtube API does not define such a concept. I have several account types (based on the account providers). Creating wrapper accounts allows me to create streaming destinations for each of them and if needed share/replace the accounts because the all account providers provide general user info (id, username, accessToken, refreshToken etc.).

Comment: @stvar title: Excellence
UserId: YjW43l5lqBVCuMrRYJDa7g
ChannelId: UCYjW43l5lqBVCuMrRYJDa7g

Comment: @stvar I agree with both you and Joakim. This is SO and its purpose is to some extent to provide support to developers. The boundaries have been crossed by Google. However, I have given and received support for previous issues with the Youtube quota on SO. There is no other way (which worked/helped) in any way at the moment.

Comment: @stvar Ah the Google issue tracker... I have reported a big issue with it and never received any feedback. The Youtube quota mechanism is kind of broken. Many developers on SO and globally were having issues with the quota audit because they waited for 1-2 years to get a quota increase (without any feedback during the time) or not depended on the success of their rain dance. Again, I agree with both you and Joakim, however, I have to take responsibility and communicate the issue (if needed) to my users.

Comment: @stvar I will try the issue tracker. Please don't delete this question because it shows a lot of issues that were created by Youtube/Google. I will post a link to this question and hope that it will motivate Google to take some action or to point me in the right direction (for future support requests).

Comment: @Darkwonder: No regular SO user -- as myself am -- is allowed to delete posted questions. Please be assured that I myself am not going to vote your question down.

Comment: @Darkwonder: The channel of which ID is `UCYjW43l5lqBVCuMrRYJDa7g` does have both `id` and `snippet.title` properties (the title is `Excellence`). Maybe you should revisit your post: am really not grasping what is then your actual problem.

Comment: @stvar Thank you for the feedback. It was not one issue, rather a number of issues. Your questions and support were breadcrumbs that lead me to the issue. I will write the answer to clarify.

Comment: @DarkWonder: Are you expecting that the result of your API call to `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id%2Csnippet&mine=true` to return a [response](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#response) containing an `items` array  having `N` elements, where `N > 1` is the number of *channels owned by the channel* having the ID `UCYjW43l5lqBVCuMrRYJDa7g`?

Comment: @stvar Yes. This does not happen when the user logins in with his Google account because he has (per default) no channel created. The API does not return an error or an empty array. It just omits to return the array.

Comment: @DarkWonder: Please confirm this once more (notice that I removed the negation from your comment above): *This **does happen** when the user logins in with his Google account because he has (per default) no channel created.* This very statement discriminates your real issue. Please update [your issue report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/181142247) too, such that Google staff to know precisely the conditions under which your issue occurs.

Comment: @DarkWonder: In my opinion, when you obtain credentials data as result of running to successful completion an OAuth authentication/authorization flow on a *Google account that has not yet been attached to a YouTube channel*, the API does respond to you correctly: the absence of `items` is not an API bug by itself, since indeed there's no YouTube channel associated for which to return metadata. In cases like this, the API could be improved to *actually return an error*; that's work for the guys implementing the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue among many other issues. The other issues helped the misunderstanding and confusion and are not relevant for this SO post.

**The Youtube Data API returns an incomplete response for the situation where the Youtube user* has no channels.**

There are three states in which the Youtube user* can be in regard to his account live streaming capabilities:

1. The user can not live stream because he has no channels.
2. The user can not live stream because his channel is not verified via phone (text message).
3. The user can live stream because his channel is verified.

The default start state for a Google user* is 1). The Google user* does not automatically own a Youtube channel. He needs to create one.
When a developer asks the API for a channel list for this user (state 1) using the url:
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id%2Csnippet&mine=true
He will receive an incorrect answer:

```
▿ 3 elements
    ▿ 0 : 2 elements
        - key : "kind"
        - value : youtube#channelListResponse
    ▿ 1 : 2 elements
        - key : "pageInfo"
        ▿ value : 2 elements
            ▿ 0 : 2 elements
                - key : resultsPerPage
                - value : 5
            ▿ 1 : 2 elements
                - key : totalResults
                - value : 0
    ▿ 2 : 2 elements
        - key : "etag"
        - value : afx3VqgXQBJVZZO3RVos5k1JEM0
```

The expected answer would be:

1. Error - "Fetching channel list failed. The user has no channel/s."

▿ 4 elements
▿ 0 : 2 elements
- key : "error"
▿ value : 1 elements
▿ 0 : 2 elements
- key : "message"
- value : "Fetching channel list failed. The user has no channel/s."
...

2. Response code 200 - "items" = [] -> just an empty array

   ▿ 4 elements
   ▿ 0 : 2 elements
   - key : "items"
   ▿ value : 0 elements

   ```
            ...

        ▿ 1 : 2 elements
            - key : "kind"
            - value : youtube#channelListResponse
        ▿ 2 : 2 elements
            - key : "pageInfo"
            ▿ value : 2 elements
                ▿ 0 : 2 elements
                    - key : resultsPerPage
                    - value : 5
                ▿ 1 : 2 elements
                    - key : totalResults
                    - value : 1
        ▿ 3 : 2 elements
            - key : "etag"
            - value : 6mudnjdaMbyKk1XIwl4DvHzx5pc
   ```

*Google and Youtube do not use Google users or Youtube users in their documentation.
To my understanding, you can have a Google account (which allows you access to other Google products) without logging into Youtube ever. When you log into Youtube the first time a small indentation appears with a username which indicates that this is actually a Youtube account. That Youtube account will not have a channel and the UI states ("No channel"). When you click the "Switch account" tab you will be able to actually switch channels if you have multiple channels. You will also be able to switch accounts.

Edit 1:

The API issue can be found [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/3/issues/181142247).

Edit 2:

The Youtube Data API "How to get help" page issue can be found [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/3/issues/181156403).

Comment: (Am reposting my comment above only because it's related to your answer.) @DarkWonder: In my opinion, when you obtain credentials data as result of running to successful completion an OAuth authentication/authorization flow on a *Google account that has not yet been attached to a YouTube channel*, the API does respond to you correctly: the absence of `items` is not an API bug by itself, since indeed there's no YouTube channel associated for which to return metadata. In cases like this, the API could be improved to *actually return an error*; that's work for the guys implementing the API.

Comment: However, the current behavior of the API is not officially documented as such. Thus, for sure one could file a documentation bug report.

Comment: A personal, side comment: I would reacted much earlier to your issue, should the API output you've been posted were JSON text. Do note  that the Google staff may well found your text uneasy to read too.

Comment: @stvar The next time I postcode I will convert the JSON text for easier readability. Thanks for your support and suggestions.